# how to translate the question into graph theory terms?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

[image]

b)Every evening, Rector Tissaia goes to all the rooms to extinguish the candles, but of course she wants to be as efficient as possible and not enter any room twice.1 Can the Rector find such a way? Justify your answer

Note: Translate the question into graph theory terms first.

Comment: I don;t understand the picture ... there seem to be corridors between some of the rooms (e.g. between 4 and 5) ... so the lack of a corridor seems to suggest that you can't move between them?  But then many rooms are isolated!  And if all rooms are supposed to have doors, so you can move between the 'islands', then what prevents the rector to just go 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11? Also, do the symbols in the rooms mean anything relevant?

Comment: i forgot to mention that the shapes are portals and that the filled ones are the entrance and empty shapes are the exit (1 filled red circle can go to 11 empty red circle) but my main question is how to translate the question i posted in graph theory terms?

Comment: OK, so you just gave an example: from 1 you can go to 11, so in a graph, have 11 nodes (vertices) for the 11 rooms, and now draw an arrow (directed edge) from 1 to 11.... and do that for all others. Then add bidirectional arrows for rooms connected with corridors (e.g. between 4 and 5) Did you create that graph yet?

Comment: yes (comment to short)

Answer (score 1):

Once you draw the graph in accordance to my instructions from the comments, you will quickly see that this is impossible. If there is a route without repeating rooms, then clearly 8 should be the start and 9 the end. Then you see that you have to get to room 2 from room 3, but from room 2 you can only get to 10 and since 10 is the only way to get to 9, the end of the route must be 3-2-10-9. But given that from 11 you can only get to 10 you have a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Just draw the graph that arises from the picture (I am assuming that the shapes that are outlines coincide with the shapes that are not outlines). Each "room" is a node, and each coinciding shape is an edge that connects each coinciding node (or room). Then, see if there is an Euler Circuit. The criteria for an Euler Circuit is that all nodes are even degree, as in each node is connected to an even amount of edges. If there is any node connected to an odd amount of edges, then there is no Euler Circuit, so Rector cannot do this.

Comment: That’s not quite right. First, we are only looking for a path, not a tour (I think... this is actually not clear) Second, the rector simply needs to visit all nodes, i.e vertices, once. An Euler tour is when you traverse all possible edges exactly once, but that is not what is needed here: maybe the rector could visit all rooms without using all portals and corridors. Third, the portals are directional, so even if all degrees are even, that does not guarantee a tour. In sum , having even degrees is neither necessary nor sufficient